# Exploring GO packages

Tags: go

Is any way to explore the GO packages?

In java, I have using "javap java.lang.String" command for viewing the method inside of the class. Something like this, Is any command is their in GO language ?

I have search the same in google. I didn't get expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go code is distributed with source and documentation tooling so you just need to search for sources in $GOROOT/src directory or use `godoc` tool  or simply go to http://golang.org/pkg/ for standard library or https://godoc.org/ for many other libraries.

On command line run `godoc <pkg name>`, example `godoc encoding/json`.

By the way, you can also get Java library sources so using `javap` for this is definitely not the shortest path. It also have documentation available online https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/